# grep exit with status 1 when found zero value

Tags: shell-script, grep

below is my code

```
1_week=$(git log --since=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 604800))")|grep '^commit ' |wc -l) && 2_week=$(git log --since=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 604800))")|grep '^Author:' |sort -u|wc -l)
```

error:

```
+ let '1_last_week += 0'
/home/mytestshell.sh exited with return code 1
```

and I tried below referring this https://blog.m157q.tw/posts/2021/06/09/be-careful-when-using-grep-on-circleci/

```
1_week=$(git log --since=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 604800))")|grep '^commit ' || true |wc -l) && 2_week=$(git log --since=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 604800))")|grep '^Author:' || true |sort -u|wc -l)
```

but it still gives exit 1 error if found value is zero, can someone guide what I am missing here

Regards,

Comment: The error message mentions `let`, `1_last_week` and `+=`, neither of which are in the code you show. What does `/home/mytestshell.sh` contain? Besides, variable names can't start with a digit.

Comment: I get `bash: let: 1_last_week: value too great for base (error token is "1_last_week")` for that `let` command. Take care to post your full script and any errors you get, it helps people help you if they don't have guess about something you didn't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which shell this is being written for, but generally variable names can't start with a digit.

I would strongly recommend that you start to paste your code into https://shellcheck.net (or install `shellcheck` locally). It will help pick up a lot of issues that you can then address directly.

Your style would benefit from improvement too. A long line of intense code isn't easy to read and understand. As a contrast here is an alternative style

```
#!/bin/sh
#
dt_since=$(date --date='1 week ago' +'%Y-%m-%d')

nr_commits=$(git log --since="$dt_since" | grep '^commit ' | wc -l)
nr_authors=$(git log --since="$dt_since" | grep '^Author:' | sort -u| wc -l)
```

You can then then perform some maths with the results in `$nr_commits` and `$nr_authors`. I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve so I've *interpreted* your `&&` as meaning you want a success (0 value) exit status if there is at least one commit from one author:

```
[ $nr_commits -gt 0 ] && [ $nr_authors -gt 0 ]
exit
```

(Note that if `$nr_commits` is non-zero then there must have been an author, so you could optimise the expression by removing the check on `$nr_authors` entirely.)

Regarding the error with `let`, there isn't any `let` in the code you have shown us so we cannot help with that.